# in drupal 7, how to add drupal_add_js in the module?

Tags: javascript, drupal, module, addition

I made a module and wish to add js file to that module, I enable the module and obvious it works. But I didn't see the js file that module should take with.

I just put the code in the hook_menu() like this

```
function my2form_menu() {
      drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'my2form') . '/abc.js');
}
```

is it ok?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you plan to always include this JS file, you should add it in the .info file of your module: http://drupal.org/node/542202#scripts

And thus you can delete your hook_menu.

Answer (score 2):

try another hook, called:
modulename_js_alter()

works fpr my porposes.